# Laravel - passing too many variable to a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have a problem in passing multiple variables from a controller to view/blade. Im using `compact()` to pass variables but I think i've reached the limit in passing variables coz i have tested my code and it would stop working after passing **30 variables**. And would give an error of: "Undefined Variable:" although it is already defined and runs perfectly not unless i pass more than 30 variables. I needed to pass many variables bcoz i am creating a chart and each value from the chart (x, y axis) is a different variable. Is there any alternative way of doing it? Im thinking about using multiple controller for a single view. Is it possible? 
Anyway, here's a snippet from my controller:

```
    $ic15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 0)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count();
    $cas15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 1)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $ce15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 2)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $uep15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 3)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $ced15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 4)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $cet15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 5)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $saec15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 6)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
    $cgb15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 7)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 


        return view('success', compact('col','school', 'total', 'f', 'm', 'ic', 'cas', 'ce', 'uep', 'ced', 'cet', 'saec', 'cgb', 'icf', 'icm', 'casf', 'casm', 'cef', 'cem', 'uepf', 'uepm', 'cedf', 'cedm', 'cetf', 'cetm', 'saecf', 'saecm', 'cgbf', 'cgbm', 'ic13', 'cas13', 'ce13', 'uep13', 'ced13', 'cet13', 'saec13', 'cgb13', 'ic14', 'cas14', 'ce14', 'uep14', 'ced14', 'cet14', 'saec14', 'cgb14', 'ic15', 'cas15', 'ce15', 'uep15', 'ced15', 'cet15', 'saec15', 'cgb15'));
```

This just a snippet, other variables were already defined before `$ic15`. It's defined and used just like the other variables from `$ic15` to `$cgb15` that is shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is such limitation to compact.But you can create a new array & put those values in that array like

```
$resultArray = array('school' => $school, 'col' => $col);
```

and in view use can get the data from like

```
print_r($resultArray['school']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer sir agam. I'll have to try your approach first... But it seems that your code is working coz someone upvoted your answer.. I'll mark this later as the answer, if it will solve my problem :))

Answer (score 1):

you may do so using the view facade's share method.

```
 $total = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')
           ->where('college_id', 0)->where('year_admitted', 2015)
           ->count();
 $school = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')
           ->where('college_id', 0)->where('year_admitted', 2015)
           ->count(); 

 view()->share('total',$total);
 view()->share('school',$school);

 return view('success');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to send them inside brackets,  change your return statement like the following one

```
            return view('success', compact(['col'],['school']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getData($id, $collegeId){
   $year = 2015;
   $school = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)
   ->groupBy('college_id')
   ->where('college_id','==', $collegeId)
   ->where('year_admitted','==', $year)
   ->count();
   return view('success', compact('school'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass variable in view like:

```
 return View::make('success', ['col' => $col,
                               'school'=> $school]);
```

OR

```
return View::make('success')
            ->with('col', $col)
            ->with('school', $school);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many variables try to put them in array like

```
$final = array();

 $ic15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 0)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count();
$cas15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 1)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
$ce15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 2)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 
$uep15 = SchoolStats::where('school_id', $id)->groupBy('college_id')->where('college_id', 3)->where('year_admitted', 2015)->count(); 

$final[] = $ic15;
$final[] = $cac15;
$final[] = $ce15;
$final[] = $uep15;
```

And then pass one variable `final` in `compact`

Now in view if you want to access your variable

Lets say you want to access `$ic15` the index would be `0` because `$ic15` was the first to get inside the array.

```
{{ $final[0] }}
```

If you want to know what variable is at what location then write `dd($final);` at the end before `return view()` of controller function of yours

Comment: How do I call the variables from the view?